# JOIN Query with COUNT and WHERE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, count

three queries I'm trying to join, 2 tables and a count the join itself works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM `AccountInfo` NATURAL JOIN `userStats` WHERE `username` = 'x'
```

i want to join it with:

```
SELECT COUNT(following) FROM `followers` WHERE `following` = 'x'
```

in order to get the number of followers following a particular user but i can't get the join to work. Any ideas?

```
 Account info:

|username|firstname|sirname |address |postcode|
|--------|-------- |--------|--------|--------|
| user1  | first   | last   |road A  |  1234  |
| user2  | name2   | last2  |road b  |  4567  |
|        |         |        |        |        |
|        |         |        |        |        |


  userStats

    |username|followers|following|lastseen |reputation|
    |--------|-------- |-------- |-------- |--------  |
    |  user1 |         |         |DD:MM:YY |  120     |
    |  user2 |         |         | DD:MM:YY|  130    |
    |        |         |         |         |          |
    |        |         |         |         |          |


followers

        |follower|following|
        |--------|-------- |
        |  user1 | user 2  | 
        |  user2 | user 1  | 
        |  user1 | user 3  | 
        |        |         |
```

The natural join successfully appends accountInfo and userStats but i would also like to count the number of followers a user has i.e how many times the users name appears in the column "following", and also how many users he follows, i.e. the amount of times the username appears in "follower". (although i didn't ask about the latter part)

For the sample data it would show: following = 2 and followers = 1

I don't mind if the data appears at the end of the concatenated table in separate columns but ideally would take the place of the following/ followers data in the userStats table

Comment: Is `username` or some other field available in the `followers` table that you can join to? Right now your second query only spits out a number, but without a `username` or `id` or something to join back into your first query, it's just a total number. A table schema or at least a list of fields for your three tables would be most helpful for us to help you.

Comment: yes there is a followers field available in userStats, i had a feeling this may call for an INNERJOIN but not quite sure how to go about it.. or perhaps

"SELECT COUNT(following) AS xyz "   and join it onto the end (the less desirable option)

Comment: Please share your tables' structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: have edited it to include what i am looking for

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What is the role of columns followers and following in table userStats? If they are counts from table follows then why do you show blanks? Which is "the concatenated table"? (The first query result?) What does "take the place of the following/ followers data in the userStats table" mean? (Update table usersStats to have the counts calculated from table followers? Drop following & followers from table userStats and just have them in the query result?) Please show example input tables and desired output table.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE `accountInfo` (
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sirname` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `userstats` (
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followers` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `following` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastseen` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reputation` int(64) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `followers` (
  `follower` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `following` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `accountInfo` (`username`, `firstname`, `sirname`, `address`, `postcode`)
VALUES
    ('user1', 'first', 'last', 'road a', '1234'),
    ('user2', 'name2', 'last2', 'road b', '4567'),
    ('user3', 'name3', 'last3', 'road c', '8974');


INSERT INTO `userstats` (`username`, `followers`, `following`, `lastseen`, `reputation`)
VALUES
    ('user1', NULL, NULL, '2015-09-22', 120),
    ('user2', NULL, NULL, '2015-09-21', 130),
    ('user3', NULL, NULL, '2015-09-20', 80);

INSERT INTO `followers` (`follower`, `following`)VALUES
('user1', 'user2'),
('user2', 'user1'),
('user1', 'user3');
```

These queries will give the number of users' followers or the number who are following the user:

```
select a.*, u.*, count(*) as number_following
from accountinfo a
    left join userstats u on(a.username = u.username)
    left join followers f1 on (u.username = f1.follower)
where 1
group by f1.follower;

select a.*, u.*, count(*) as number_of_followers
from accountinfo a
    left join userstats u on(a.username = u.username)
    left join followers f1 on (u.username = f1.following)
where 1
group by f1.following;
```

(update 9/26/15)
You can use a subquery in the left join with a group by to pull the counts like:

```
    select a.*, u.*, f1.*, f2.*
   from accountinfo a
        left join userstats u on(a.username = u.username)
        left join (select f.follower as username, count(*) as following_count from followers f group by f.follower) f1 on (u.username = f1.username)
        left join (select f.following as username, count(*) as followers_count from followers f group by f.following) f2 on (u.username = f2.username)
    where 1;
```

Comment: Thanks so much it works!.. 
Im quite confident, after reading this that I understand how it works but would you mind explaining the particulars. 

Im asking because i notice if i search for a username that has zero followers (does not appear in the follower column) the number_following returns a result of 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @philipxy what i meant is that even for a user 'userX' whose name does not appear in followers.follower, the query returns 1 instead of 0 for table f1 described above

Comment: @ J. R. & @vitamike If there are no u.followX for a user then left join with f1 gives a row with that user and NULL u.followX. GROUP BY creates a group of 1 row for each of those users. `COUNT(*)` includes NULLs so gives 1 for those users. You want `COUNT(f1.followX)` because `COUNT` of a column doesn't count NULLs.  PS WHERE 1 is not needed.

Comment: @vitamike My comment about 0 vs NULL was unrelated to your comment about 1 vs 0. (But my comment was really about userStats not these queries.)

Comment: @philipxy I edited my answer to add another query that will only count the rows from the followers table and not yeild a count of 1 for userX

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your inputs and desired output but let's say we have the following predicates (parameterized statements):

```
// user `username` named `firstname` `surname` lives at ...
// == `AccountInfo`(`username`,`firstname`,`surname`,...)

// user `username` was last seen at `lastseen` and ...
// == `userStats`(`username`,`lastseen`,...)

// user `follower` follows user `following`
// == `followers`(`follower`,`following`)
```

(My `userStats` has no `followers` & `following` count columns.)

After each predicate (parameterized statement) I have written a shorthand for it. Each shorthand is like `SQL CREATE TABLE`. A table (base or query result) holds rows that make a true proposition (statement) from its predicate.

(My answer continues using `NATURAL JOIN` as in your question.)

The table of rows satisfying the AND of two base table predicates is the `NATURAL JOIN` of their tables:

```
//     user `username` named `firstname` `surname` lives at ...
// AND user `username` was last seen at `lastseen` and ...
// ==   `AccountInfo`(`username`,`firstname`,`surname`,...)
// AND `userStats`(`username`,`lastseen`,...)
SELECT * FROM `AccountInfo` NATURAL JOIN `userStats`
```

The rows satisfying AND of a base table predicate and a condition is the base table `WHERE` the condition:

```
//     `AccountInfo`(`username`,`firstname`,`surname`,...)
// AND `userStats`(`username`,`lastseen`,...)
// AND `username` = 'x'
SELECT * FROM `AccountInfo` NATURAL JOIN `userStats` WHERE `username` = 'x'
```

Now each user's follower and following counts:

```
// user `username` follows user `following`
// == `followers`(`username`,`following`)
SELECT `follower` AS `username` FROM `followers`

// user `username` follows `followers` users
CREATE TABLE `nfollowing`
SELECT `follower` AS `username`, COUNT(`following`) AS following
FROM followers
GROUP BY `follower`

//    user `username` has follower `follower`
// == user `follower` follows user `username`
// == followers(`follower`,`username`)
SELECT `following` AS `username` FROM `followers`

// user `username` has `followers` followers
CREATE TABLE `nfollowers`
SELECT `following` AS `username`, COUNT(`follower`) AS followers
FROM followers
GROUP BY `following`
```

We want rows satisfying the AND of those predicates, which are the rows in the `NATURAL JOIN` of their tables:

```
// user `username` has `followers` followers and follows `following` users
// ==  user `username` has `followers` followers
// AND user `username` follows `following` users
CREATE TABLE `nfollow`
SELECT * FROM `nfollowers` NATURAL JOIN `nfollowing`
```

Now your userStats is:

```
SELECT * FROM `userStats` NATURAL JOIN `nfollow`
```

The query you want might be:

```
SELECT * FROM
   `AccountInfo` NATURAL JOIN `userStats` NATURAL JOIN `nfollow`
WHERE `username` = 'x'
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation

Comment: This has errors I'll fix: nfollowX predicates should be "...and followX > 0" and (hence) the other expressions do not have rows for followX = 0.